# VIEW PDF 404 LARAVEL 7

Tags: php, html, laravel, file-upload, upload

I want to have a button where a client can view an applicant's document that the candidate has uploaded, but for some reason I cannot figure out why it doesn't work.

It was working fine offline, but I deployed the site via FTP today and It doesn't want to work.

I am less than a junior developer so please be kind about messy code,

Here is my code for

upload blade:

```
 <form action="{{route('cv')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">@csrf
 <div class="card">        
 <div class="card-header">Update CV</div>
 <div class="card-body">
 <input type="file" class="form-control" name="cv"><br>
  <button class="btn btn-success float-right"
  type="submit">Update</button>
  @if($errors->has('cv'))
   <div class="error" style="color: red;">{{$errors->first('cv')}}</div>
                             @endif 
                            </div>
                            </div>
```

Code for route:

```
Route::post('user/cv','UserController@cv')->name('cv');
```

Code for Controller:

```
public function cv(Request $request){
    $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $cv = $request->file('cv')->store(public_path('storage/files'));
    Profile::where('user_id',$user_id)->update(['cv'=>$request->file('cv')->getClientOriginalName()]);
    
    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'CV Successfully Updated!');
 }
```

Code for viewing the CV :

```
<a href="{{Storage::url($profile->cv)}}" class="btn btn-outline-primary">View my CV</a>
```

When I click the button I get this url:

```
cvroad.co.za/storage/Kevin%20Breed.pdf
```

The name of the file is : Kevin Breed.pdf and that is how it is seen in my database aswell.

but still 404 not found?

Any and all help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: I betcha `/home/cvroazdi/public_html/storage/files` doesn't exist on both systems

Comment: @aynber that's correct, it used to be " ->store('public/files'); when it was on my localhost...? should I not have changed it ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hard-coding the file path, use Laravel's [`storage_path()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-storage-path) to get to the right path.

```
$cv = $request->file('cv')->store(storage_path('files'));
```

Though if you're using `Storage::url()`, then it's looking in `public/storage`, so the proper way to go about it might to use the public_path

```
$cv = $request->file('cv')->store(public_path('storage/files'));
```

Also when saving to the database, you're saving the full path, not just the name. You can store just the name like this:

```
Profile::where('user_id',$user_id)->update(['cv'=>$request->file('cv')->getClientOriginalName()]);
```

Comment: still getting 404 not found - and url is "https://www.cvroad.co.za/storage/home/cvroazdi/cvapp/storage/files/q9PJBXoWScBcL3QoiBtukpimL0i2bbZCCNcpThkx.pdf"

Comment: Sorry, I updated the answer to use public_path as well

Comment: okay, I changed it to be that, however, I am still getting error 404 and url "https://www.cvroad.co.za/storage/home/cvroazdi/cvapp/public/storage/files/p0WGFGY"

Comment: I think at this point that the storage is correct, but `$profile->cv` is probably incorrect. It's storing the full directory, not the just the file name.

Comment: Hi Aynber, I have got it to the point where It is only storing the filname like you suggested, it appears to go to the correct path, but still doesn't show?

Comment: What does the exact path in the URL show?

Comment: The exact URL after clicking 
https://www.cvroad.co.za/home/cvroazdi/public_html/storage/files/cv/Kevin%20Breed.pdf




The name of the file: Kevin Breed

@aynber

Comment: Your path is still wrong. The URL should not show `/home/cvroazdi/public_html` at all. Double-check your profile to see what is stored in `cv`

Comment: Also in your artisan tinker, try `Storage::url('test');` to see the path it shows, just to double-check that value.

Comment: I think I am starting to understand what you are saying- where is it supposed to go then? @aynber

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241494/discussion-between-martin-and-aynber).